# is there anything wrong with this javascript and php codes?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web, charts

I was doing query from database. But the data result is incorrect from the database. my table of db is
[image]

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
//app.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var Gender = [];
            var jumlah = [];
            var Fakultas = [];
            var jumlah_orang = [];

            for(var i in data)
        {
            //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
            if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1)
            {
                Gender.push("Men");
            } 
            if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2)
            {
                Gender.push("Women");
            }

            jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "A")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPERTA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "B")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FKH");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "C")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FPIK");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "D")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPET");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "E")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAHUTAN");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "F")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FATETA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "G")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FMIPA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "H")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEM");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "I")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEMA");
            }

            jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);
        }
        Gender.push("Other");
        Fakultas.push("Other");
            var chartdata = {
                labels: Gender,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label : 'Total',
                        backgroundColor: 
                        [
                            'rgba(79, 181, 59, 1)', //green for men
                            'rgba(239, 87, 196, 1)', //pink for women
                            'rgba(166, 160, 164, 1)', //grey for other
                        ],
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: jumlah
                    }
                ]
            };

            var chartdata2 = {
                labels: Fakultas,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label : 'Total',
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(79, 181, 59, 1)',
                            'rgba(239, 87, 196, 1)', 
                            'rgba(166, 160, 164, 1)', 
                            'rgba(96, 60, 64, 1)', 
                            'rgba(66, 16, 164, 1)', 
                            'rgba(177, 18, 74, 1)', 
                            'rgba(176, 60, 64, 1)', 
                            'rgba(186, 10, 64, 1)', 
],
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: jumlah_orang
                    }
                ]
};

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
            var ctx2 = $("#mycanvas2");


            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata

            });

            var barGraph2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata2

            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbintegrasi');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT JenisKelaminID, COUNT(JenisKelaminID) as jumlah FROM tahunmasukmagister GROUP BY JenisKelaminID");
$query2 = sprintf("SELECT Fakultas, COUNT(Fakultas) as jumlah_orang FROM s2view GROUP BY Fakultas");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();

foreach ($result as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}

foreach ($result2 as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}

//freee memory associated with result
$result->close();
$result2->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//new print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

The chart result for "fakultas" came like this
[image]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgX6h.png
```

as we can see, in the table "Fakultas G" (FMIPA) is 3 but on the chart result Fakultas G is 3. What's wrong with those codes? Please help me to solve this. Thankyou

Comment: from just a quick glance: in your php in your second foreach statement:  Wouldn't that just override everything you just added from $result?

Comment: so, how should I type that code? I dont get it @CodeCabin

Comment: Can u check what query is returning? it is the same you mentioned at top?

Comment: At looking up your code it seems it's taking 3 first value blank, because you are writing - jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang); jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);  these two statement together have non common values Gender and fakultas, so you need to write it in if else and you are not handling 'P' of Fakultas. So three blanks values are taken at first 3 places.

Comment: so how I should type the codes? Could you please make it in the answer colomn? @AfshanShujat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the logic of data parsing inside for loop-

```
if(typeof data[i].JenisKelaminID !== 'undefined'){

      if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1)
        {
            Gender.push("Men");
        } 
        if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2)
        {
            Gender.push("Women");
        }

        jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);
}

if(typeof data[i].Fakulta !== 'undefined'){

      if(data[i].Fakultas == "A")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPERTA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "B")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FKH");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "C")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FPIK");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "D")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPET");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "E")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAHUTAN");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "F")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FATETA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "G")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FMIPA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "H")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEM");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "I")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEMA");
            }

            jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: it works @Asfhan Shujat. Thankyou for helping me to solve this problem. GBU

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode json data in jquery as you have encoded it in php.

Comment: how is the way? @AjayDhul

Comment: url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {//use here                                                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//then you can parse through obj easily